# How to change Key file in Amazon EC2 [without shutdown or IP change]?

Tags: 16.04, ssh, amazon-ec2

I've shared the FTP details (key files, IP & Username), so now i would like to change the Key file.

Ubuntu Version - 16.04

Please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: Hello Arpit , you cannot change .pem key of ec2 instance for that u need to create new instance with new .pem key and tansfer that old instance disk to new created instance in that way you can change .pem key.

Comment: @MayurBhandare We can change the Key files without creating new instance. I've found the solution and it worked for me.

Comment: Great job dude can you explain